# Can't get picture in my view in mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc

When I'm in Category controller - Index View and click a some category from dropdown I should be redirected to details view.

I get from database the path that is saved in a string property ImageUrl in my CategoryViewModel and its value is "Images/safe_image.jpg" as my image is in The Image folder of the mvc appliacvtion.

So basically in the viewmodel I've got

```
    @model OnlineStore.Commercial.Models.CategoryViewModel

                   <img src="@Model.ImageUrl"/>
```

But for some reason the server makes this request to get the Image

```
    http://localhost:56469/Category/Images/safe_image.jpg
```

And so It doesn't get it.

Comment: <img src="@Url.Content(Model.ImagePath)" alt="Image" />

Answer (score 3):

Let the [`Url.Content`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.urlhelper.content%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) to resolve the path for you.

```
<img src="@Url.Content(Model.ImageUrl)"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

The pathing you have specified is relative to the current URL. Try this absolute path instead (if your images folder is indeed off the root):

```
  <img src="/@Model.ImageUrl"/>
```

You could also leverage the tilde sign to ensure that any virtual directories will resolve properly as well:

```
@Url.Content("~/" + Model.Image)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<img src="@Url.Content(Model.ImagePath)" alt="Image" />
```